# C# Group by list by specific element to result a list of lists

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I have a `list` of objects. Every object has these components: `index, countNr, descA, descB.`

How I can group by (maybe LINQ) this `list` by `countNr` value?

Like:

List = `{(1,3,a1,b1), (2,2,a2,b2), (3,2,a3,b3), (4,1,a4,b4), (5,1,a5,b5), (6,1,a6,b6), (7,1,a7,b7)}`

I want now to have another `newList` of lists, where the position in this list is indicating the `countNr` number, like:

```
newList = {{(7,1,a7,b7), (6,1,a6,b6), (5,1,a5,b5), (4,1,a4,b4)},  {(3,2,a3,b3), (2,2,a2,b2)},  {(1,3,a1,b1)}}
```

Comment: Please show a valid compiling example of input list and what you have tried (using linq). There are many examples for a simple group by usage

Comment: Maybe this : var results = myList.GroupBy(x => ((object[])x)[1]).OrderBy(x => x.Key).Select(x => x.OrderByDescending(y => ((object[])y)[0])).SelectMany(x => x).ToList();

Comment: Please follow Gilad Green's suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

If your class, looks like this:

```
public class MyClass
{

    public MyClass(int index, int countNr, string descA, string descB)
    {
        Index = index;
        CountNr = countNr;
        DescA = descA;
        DescB = descB;
    }
    public int Index { get; set; }
    public int CountNr { get; set; }
    public string DescA { get; set; }
    public string DescB { get; set; }
}
```

And this input:

```
var list = new List<MyClass> {
    new MyClass(1, 3, "a1", "b1"),
    new MyClass(2, 2, "a2", "b2"),
    new MyClass (3, 2, "a3", "b3"),
    new MyClass(4, 1, "a4", "b4"),
    new MyClass(5, 1, "a5", "b5"),
    new MyClass(6, 1, "a6", "b6"),
    new MyClass(7, 1, "a7", "b7") };
```

You can try it:

```
var query = from r in list
    group r by new { r.CountNr } into grp
    orderby grp.Key.CountNr ascending
    select new
    {
        grp.Key.CountNr,
        grp
    };
```

Then you have this :

```
foreach (var item in query)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"CountNr: {item.CountNr}"); //Key  or group
    //All rows of group
    foreach (var g in item.grp)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"{g.Index} - {g.CountNr} - {g.DescA} - {g.DescB}");
    }                
}
```

And this result:

```
CountNr: 1
4 - 1 - a4 - b4
5 - 1 - a5 - b5
6 - 1 - a6 - b6
7 - 1 - a7 - b7
CountNr: 2
2 - 2 - a2 - b2
3 - 2 - a3 - b3
CountNr: 3
1 - 3 - a1 - b1
```

If you need to order by index too. Try this:

```
var query = from r in list
    group r by new { r.CountNr } into grp
    orderby grp.Key.CountNr ascending
    select new
    {
        grp.Key.CountNr,
        grp =grp.OrderByDescending( c=> c.Index)
    };
```

And you have this result:

```
CountNr: 1
7 - 1 - a7 - b7
6 - 1 - a6 - b6
5 - 1 - a5 - b5
4 - 1 - a4 - b4
CountNr: 2
3 - 2 - a3 - b3
2 - 2 - a2 - b2
CountNr: 3
1 - 3 - a1 - b1
```

Att.

Comment: Please show the OP's input as valid C# code and then the output that your code gives.

Comment: The input and the expected output were in question. But already includes in my reply.

Comment: Isn't 7 the first expected value (not 4)?

Comment: In the question say only to ordering by countNr value. So I do that.

Comment: I edited my reply and includes option ordering by Index also.

Answer (score 1):

`newList = list.OrderBy(z => z.countNr).ThenByDescending(y => y.index).ToList()`

is probably what you want. I think it may generate your sample output based on your sample input.

Or a complete code sample:

```
class Bob
{
    public int index;
    public int countNr;
    public string descA;
    public string descB;

    public Bob(int index, int countNr, string descA, string descB)
    {
        this.index = index;
        this.countNr = countNr;
        this.descA = descA;
        this.descB = descB;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{index} - {countNr} - {descA} - {descB}";
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var list = new List<Bob>
        {
            new Bob(1, 3, "a1", "b1"),
            new Bob(2, 2, "a2", "b2"),
            new Bob(3, 2, "a3", "b3"),
            new Bob(4, 1, "a4", "b4"),
            new Bob(5, 1, "a5", "b5"),
            new Bob(6, 1, "a6", "b6"),
            new Bob(7, 1, "a7", "b7")
        };

        var newList = list.OrderBy(z => z.countNr).ThenByDescending(y => y.index).ToList();

        newList.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

which gives:

```
7 - 1 - a7 - b7
6 - 1 - a6 - b6
5 - 1 - a5 - b5
4 - 1 - a4 - b4
3 - 2 - a3 - b3
2 - 2 - a2 - b2
1 - 3 - a1 - b1
```

Comment: Please show the OP's input as valid C# code and then the output that your code gives.

Comment: "It will generate your sample output based on your simple input." - Show us please.

Comment: Done as requested!

Comment: It's not for my benefit. It's for the community. That's what SO is about.

Comment: You are correct @Enigmativity - apologies for the snark.